# Install 2 wildcard SSL cert in one static IP

Tags: ssl, static, wildcard, iis-8

I have 2 wildcard SSL need to install in 1 server (only have 1 static IP)
Server running window 2012 and IIS8

This is 2 SSL cert

**SSL1** : *.mywebone.com

**SSL2** : *.mywebtwo.com

Now the problem is : after setup SSL2 successful, SSL1 will got error.
Cannot active both of them in same time.

Please help me resolve
Because in technical cannot install 2 wildcard SSL in the same IP address ?
Do i need to buy one more static IP ?

Comment: IIS is not doing a very good job telling what's wrong in there. Usually you need an IP per certificate and that's why IIS cannot use both certificates (as you need 2 IP's in this case). But as noted in the answer below you can use SNI instead. It's also possible to do some voodoo tricks to let IIS use various IP's, but I IIS-8 should support SNI.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to buy another IP.

The process of configuration multiple certificates have been simplified by using Server Name Indication (SNI) technology. You should choose SNI SSL option during the wildcard certificate installation which will allow you to configure multiple certificates on a single IP address.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Install+an+SSL+Certificate+on+a+Domain#InstallanSSLCertificateonaDomain-SNIandmultiplecertificates